# how to consider comma separated field as a single field in perl

Tags: perl

I have an input CSV file.

```
model,taccode,               date

1001,234ghy,               20151120

1002,hj3456,531908jh       20151120

1003,56789ui,78fgby,34s2fg,20151120
```

When I parse the CSV file using `,` as the delimiter I am able to insert the rows into a temp table.

```
while (<CSVFILE>) {
                $line = $_;
                ($field1,$field2,$startDate)=split(/,/,trim($line));

                if($field2 eq "")
                {
                    $field2=0;
                }

                $Loaddatainsertsql->bind_param(1,$field1);
                $Loaddatainsertsql->bind_param(2,$field2);
                $Loaddatainsertsql->bind_param(3,$startDate);
                $Loaddatainsertsql->execute ();
}
```

Data output in a table:

```
model  taccode                date

1001   234ghy                20151120

1002   hj3456,531908jh        20151120

1003   56789ui,78fgby,34s2fg  20151120
```

Can any one please help me out.

Comment: I think what you're asking is how to deal with that middle field that has multiple commas, but could you make that more clear?  Are you sure the original file is delimited by `,` and not something like tab?  Or perhaps the fields are of fixed size.

Comment: comma separated fields is the input file.when im trying to parse1002 and 1003 these are taking only first values

Comment: yes original file is separated by , only

Comment: Can you modify the source data at all, or is it outside of your control?

Comment: @ramkys The original file sure looks fixed-width to me.  Otherwise why have all that space between the columns?  Could you post a portion of the original somewhere that will preserve all the spacing, like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: Rather than editing your post and completely changing the problem, you should revert the changes and post a new question if you have a different problem.

Answer (score 6):

The best solution would be to enclose your values in quotes and use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) to parse the file correctly. If you don't have control over the original data source and the columns are anchored somehow (e.g., first two, first three, or first and last as in your case), you can do something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split(/,/, $_);

    my $first  = shift(@fields);
    my $last   = pop(@fields);
    my $middle = join(',', @fields);

    printf("%-16s%-59s%s\n", $first, $middle, $last);
}

__DATA__
lifelock,LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-May-07,6850000,USD,b
lifelock,LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-Oct-06,6000000,USD,a
lifelock,LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-Jan-08,25000000,USD,c
mycityfaces,MyCityFaces,7,web,Scottsdale,AZ,1-Jan-08,50000,USD,seed
flypaper,Flypaper,,web,Phoenix,AZ,1-Feb-08,3000000,USD,a
infusionsoft,Infusionsoft,105,software,Gilbert,AZ,1-Oct-07,9000000,USD,a
gauto,gAuto,4,web,Scottsdale,AZ,1-Jan-08,250000,USD,seed
chosenlist-com,ChosenList.com,5,web,Scottsdale,AZ,1-Oct-06,140000,USD,seed
chosenlist-com,ChosenList.com,5,web,Scottsdale,AZ,25-Jan-08,233750,USD,angel
digg,Digg,60,web,San Francisco,CA,1-Dec-06,8500000,USD,b
digg,Digg,60,web,San Francisco,CA,1-Oct-05,2800000,USD,a
facebook,Facebook,450,web,Palo Alto,CA,1-Sep-04,500000,USD,angel
facebook,Facebook,450,web,Palo Alto,CA,1-May-05,12700000,USD,a
facebook,Facebook,450,web,Palo Alto,CA,1-Apr-06,27500000,USD,b
facebook,Facebook,450,web,Palo Alto,CA,1-Oct-07,300000000,USD,c
facebook,Facebook,450,web,Palo Alto,CA,1-Mar-08,40000000,USD,c
facebook,Facebook,450,web,Palo Alto,CA,15-Jan-08,15000000,USD,c
facebook,Facebook,450,web,Palo Alto,CA,1-May-08,100000000,USD,debt_round
```

Output:

```
lifelock        LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-May-07,6850000,USD                b
lifelock        LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-Oct-06,6000000,USD                a
lifelock        LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-Jan-08,25000000,USD               c
mycityfaces     MyCityFaces,7,web,Scottsdale,AZ,1-Jan-08,50000,USD         seed
flypaper        Flypaper,,web,Phoenix,AZ,1-Feb-08,3000000,USD              a
infusionsoft    Infusionsoft,105,software,Gilbert,AZ,1-Oct-07,9000000,USD  a
gauto           gAuto,4,web,Scottsdale,AZ,1-Jan-08,250000,USD              seed
chosenlist-com  ChosenList.com,5,web,Scottsdale,AZ,1-Oct-06,140000,USD     seed
chosenlist-com  ChosenList.com,5,web,Scottsdale,AZ,25-Jan-08,233750,USD    angel
digg            Digg,60,web,San Francisco,CA,1-Dec-06,8500000,USD          b
digg            Digg,60,web,San Francisco,CA,1-Oct-05,2800000,USD          a
facebook        Facebook,450,web,Palo Alto,CA,1-Sep-04,500000,USD          angel
facebook        Facebook,450,web,Palo Alto,CA,1-May-05,12700000,USD        a
facebook        Facebook,450,web,Palo Alto,CA,1-Apr-06,27500000,USD        b
facebook        Facebook,450,web,Palo Alto,CA,1-Oct-07,300000000,USD       c
facebook        Facebook,450,web,Palo Alto,CA,1-Mar-08,40000000,USD        c
facebook        Facebook,450,web,Palo Alto,CA,15-Jan-08,15000000,USD       c
facebook        Facebook,450,web,Palo Alto,CA,1-May-08,100000000,USD       debt_round
```

This problem becomes trivial to solve using Text::CSV if your fields are quoted properly from the start, though the meaning of *properly* when referring to CSV is kind of [up for debate](https://github.com/parsecsv/csv-spec). At any rate, enclosing fields in double quotes is pretty well understood:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;

while (<DATA>) {
    $csv->parse($_);
    my @fields = $csv->fields;
    dd(\@fields);
}

__DATA__
lifelock,"LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-May-07,6850000,USD",b
lifelock,"LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-Oct-06,6000000,USD",a
lifelock,"LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-Jan-08,25000000,USD",c
mycityfaces,"MyCityFaces,7,web,Scottsdale,AZ,1-Jan-08,50000,USD",seed
flypaper,"Flypaper,,web,Phoenix,AZ,1-Feb-08,3000000,USD",a
infusionsoft,"Infusionsoft,105,software,Gilbert,AZ,1-Oct-07,9000000,USD",a
```

Output:

```
["lifelock", "LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-May-07,6850000,USD", "b"]
["lifelock", "LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-Oct-06,6000000,USD", "a"]
[
  "lifelock",
  "LifeLock,,web,Tempe,AZ,1-Jan-08,25000000,USD",
  "c",
]
[
  "mycityfaces",
  "MyCityFaces,7,web,Scottsdale,AZ,1-Jan-08,50000,USD",
  "seed",
]
[
  "flypaper",
  "Flypaper,,web,Phoenix,AZ,1-Feb-08,3000000,USD",
  "a",
]
[
  "infusionsoft",
  "Infusionsoft,105,software,Gilbert,AZ,1-Oct-07,9000000,USD",
  "a",
]
```

Comment: Jacob Yes, I agree there should be double quotes for the second field.can you please help me out how to parse the double quote string .I am new to perl

Comment: Not just for the second field, but for every field! Click the Text::CSV link in my answer for examples on how to use that module. The documentation is pretty good, and there are plenty of Text::CSV examples on SO as well.

Comment: @ramkys If you can modify the source data (which is why I asked that question on your original post), using Text::CSV is the best way to go in terms of maintainability and correctness. I updated my answer with an example.